# Testing hibernate entity on H2

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-data, h2

I am a fan of TDD and I refuse to push untested code.  In production, I am using mysql version 5.7.  I wish to use H2 in my unit tests.

I have a very simple entity called `Message` define as bellow.

```
package com.question.domain;


import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = MessageEntity.TABLE)
public class MessageEntity {

    public static final String TABLE = "question";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE = "massage";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = COLUMN_MESSAGE, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci")
    private String message;

}
```

My tests are blowing up because h2 does not support `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as column type.  Is there a way I can tell hibernate to use `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` only with mysql?

I would imagine hibernate would have additional annotations that tune different backends.  Something like:

```
@Audited
@MysqlColumn(name = COLUMN_MESSAGE, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci")
private String message;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Hibernate to create the database schema in the first place. FlywayDB or Liquibase are the right tools for the job. But I wouldn't tet code that is supposed to run on MySQL with H2 either.That's the best way to have tests that pass although the code will fail in production, or vice-versa.

Comment: I really like your views.  Unfortunately, your propose changes would require a couple of million lines refactoring.  #reallife

Comment: Why would code supposed to run on MySQL require a million lines refactoring to be tested on MySQL?